# Plugin to apply search filtering in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins

I am a student learning wordpress these days while working with wordpress i though to implement the search filters on my website by default wordpress searches the posts i want to apply filters on search. Let me explain in simple words what i want to do. I have a number of products in my database table a user can search a product by its unique id or by its name. When a user will search select drop down this will show him following options to search with unique id(Brand ID). He may search a product that is being start with specific entered word. I am worried how i can alter the search query of wordpress. If anyone can help me in doing this task? I will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this code helps you a bit  to start.

```
function ba_SearchFilter($query) {
    if (!$query->is_search) {
        return $query;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cat'])){
        $query->set('category__and', $_POST['cat']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tags'])){
        $query->set('tag__and', $_POST['tags']);
    }
    return $query;
}
//hook filters to search
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ba_SearchFilter');

function ba_search_with_filters(){
    $out = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="'. home_url( '/' ).'">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" /><br />';
            $categories=  get_categories(); 
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $option = '';
                $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="cat[]" value="'.$category->term_id.'"> ';
                $option .= $category->cat_name .'<br />';
                $out.= $option;
            }
            $tags=  get_categories(); 
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $option = '';
                $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id="tags[]" value="'.$tag->term_id.'"> ';
                $option .= $tag->cat_name .'<br />';
                $out.= $option;
            }
    $out .='<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        </form>';
    return $out;
}

add_shortcode('search_with_filter','ba_search_with_filters');

?>
```

You have to change the code as your requirement. Also you can see the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/

Comment: I am trying to work with the plugin you have mentioned. I am trying to add a custom field and then i want to add three options in dropdown menu 1)search by start. 2) Search exactly 3) Search end with Plugin doesn't allow me to add items in drop down list. Thanks..